# Mypy: Execute functions on a list of classes -> "error": "object" has no attribute "my_function"

Tags: python, mypy

MyPy complains `error: "object" has no attribute "my_function"  [attr-defined]` when I iterate over a list of classes and execute a function for each class:

```py
    list_of_classes = [ClassA(), ClassB(), ...]
    for current_class in list_of_classes:
        result = current_class.my_function(arguments)
```

The code is working fine, its just that mypy has a problem with it. Do I need to declare the classes in a special way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the definition of a class. Making them inherit from common interface (or Abstract Base Class as it's known in Python) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without type hints, `mypy` infers the type of `list_of_classes` to be `list[object]`, as `object` appears to be the most specific base class that `ClassA` et al. have in common. If `current_class` is only known to be an instance of `object`, one cannot assume it has a `my_function` attribute.

Options include:

1. Using *nominal subtyping*. Under nominal subtyping, `A` is a subtype of `B` if `A` is a subclass of `B`.

   Define a base class that defines `my_function` and have `ClassA` et al. inherit from that base class. Type inference should then choose that base class as the most specific class that all your classes inherit from. (If not, you can use an explicit type hint `list_of_classes: list[Base] = ...` (where `Base` is the base class you defined).
2. Using *structural subtyping*. Under structural subtyping, `A` is a subtype of `B` if `A` has (at least) the same attributes as `B`.

   Define a protocol for classes that have `my_function` and provide an explicit type hint for `list_of_classes`.

   ```
    class HasMyFunction(typing.Protocol):
        def my_function(self, x):
            ...


    ...

    list_of_classes: list[HasMyFunction] = [ClassA(), ClassB()]
   ```

   Any type providing a `my_function` attribute will be considered a subtype of `HasMyFunction`.